# Seeding wordpress custom post with sample data

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am building a wordpress site for a client. The concept they want to use is having a restaurant-menu be used as a boilerplate, but making fields like price and/or food items adjustable on a per location basis.

The approach I would like to use is:

1. Use custom post types
2. Use advanced custom fields
3. Pre populate the **custom post type** with sample data that will automatically be reproduced every time I create a **new post**

With **3.** I am hitting a roadblock. I am looking for either a simple , plugin based way to achieve this or a PHP driven db insertion function. Doesn't matter to me, whatever works. Any resources would help!

Thanks

On [this post](http://ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727206/pre-fill-content-title-and-custom-fields-to-new-posts-with-custom-post-type-i) the approach suggests using the **wp_insert_post_data** function

```
if (isAdmin()){

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','custom_insert_post', '99', 2);

function custom_insert_post($data, $postarr){ <-- 
    $data['post_title'] = 'default_post_title';
    $data['post_status'] = 'future'; 
    //.... etc            


}}
```

I worry about the limitations of hard coding the database insertion if the ACF keys are changed in a future iteration, affecting the seeding method I've created initially. So I'm wondering if there is a plugin that allows me to pre-populate a given post type (id, key, ...etc), or a post in stack overflow that has solved a similar problem. Ideally, I'd like to have a given post generated in a GUI and then have that first insertion prepopulated in subsequent posts.

**Desired output in wordpress back end**

[image]

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your feedback, I'll make my post more specific, and define my approach more closely